# Cloud event transfer over an URL in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloudevents

I have one cloud event in my code which contains byte data, now I want to send this cloud event to a URL. I've tried Feign client and rest template but not able to send the cloud event. Can anyone help me here, how can I do this?
In Quarkus I used @RegisterRestClien and @RestClient Combination to send it and it works perfectly but how can I send it in spring boot?

Comment: Why use REST instead of a message queue such Kafka or NATS?

Comment: The URL on which I want to send my cloud Event belongs to KNative API, which will perform certain processing based on cloud-event data.

Comment: KNative also supports message queues

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I was trying to send a CloudEvent object directly which I guess not supported by spring boot (I also rovided all necessary dependencies in pom.xml) but it was not working. But cloud event is only a json data with some specific field like specVersion, type etc. in it's header, So i created a json structure where all these fields (ce-specVersion, ce-type etc) I put in header and then send this using restTemplate and it worked like below -

```
    import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("ce-specversion", "1.0");
    // Set Remaining fields

    byte[] bytesData = 
    JSON_DATA_IN_FORM_OF_STRING.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    HttpEntity<byte[]> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bytesData, headers);

    restTemplate.postForLocation(sinkUrl, httpEntity);
```

But remember one thing if you are sending any field in header then it should contain 'ce-' as prefix (Apart from the Data that we are sending in HttpEntity) like in my case there was one key 'partitionKey' so I send it as 'ce-partitionKey'.